# Procedure that generate the polynomial coefficients and a function to calculate the value of it

Tags: c++, math, pascal, polynomials

So essentially, I'm trying to code a small block that should create or generate coefficients for polynomial n-degree that can be represented through vector which is a=[a0, a1..an] given the basic formula is

> [image: formula of polynomial]

Well, the issue is when doing a function to get value of polynomial P from point "x" it returns value from entirely using Horner's Rule which it's not the same result as intended although not sure which one I should put on. The math basic explanation tells me at least something out of:

> E.g: n=2; (*A[i]* stack terms by 4, 2, 1) and calculates P(*value of x*) = 4 * x ^ 0 – 2 * x ^ 1  + 1 * x ^ 2 = 4 – 2x + x2 = x2 – 2x + 4 = 4

With other words , can't find the culprit when for "x" value is meant to go through "i" variable numbered wrong by exponent and the result gets output for P(0)=7 while it shouldn't be and concrete as in P(0) = 0 ^ 2 – 2 * 0 + 4 = 4

Here's a little snippet went through so far, I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
double horner(const double&x, const int& n, const double& nn) {
    if (n < 0)
        return nn;
     else {
        double m; cin>>m;
        return horner(x, n-1, nn*x+m);
     }
}
int main() {
    int n;double x;
    cout << "n=";cin >> n;
    cout << "x=";cin >> x;
    cout << "P(0)=" << horner(x, n, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: My brain farted for a moment somewhere while was coding and continuously revising the case, I forgot to mention what exactly are the parts of each variables for the program to avoid confusion yes, so:

- n, polynomial grade;
- p, polynomial coefficient;
- x, the point in which evaluates;

And here given the grade equation to polynomial

[image]

which any negative and positive input terms adding by exponent to these coefficients are the steps that holds the result exception, hence the reason Horner's rule that it reduces the number of multiplication operations.

Edit: After few hours, managed to fix with polynomial evaluating issue, the only question remains how I'd suppose to generate coefficients using method  **std::vector** ?

```
float honer(float p[], int n, float x)
{
    int i;
    float val;
    val = p[n];
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        val = val * x + p[i];
    return val;
}
int main()
{

    float p[20]; // Coefficient of the initial polynomial
    int n;       // Polynomial degree -n
    float x;     // Value that evaluates P -> X
    cout << "(n) =  ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = n; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << "A[" << i << "]=";
        cin >> p[i];
    }
    cout << "x:= ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "P(" << x << ")=" << honer(p, n, x);

    //Result (input):
    //n: 2,
    //P[i]: 4, -2, 1 -> x: 0, 1
    // Result (output):
    //P() = 4
}
```

Expect some certain output scenarios given below input if assigned:

[image]

Comment: This might be a good time to learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Another couple of notes: If you expect a certain output, then always please specify the exact input you give, inside the question itself (or for testing, hard-code the input). Also there's no need to pass the arguments to your `horner` function by reference.

Comment: IMHO, you should input all the coefficients first and eliminate the `cin>>m` inside the `horner` function.  Because of the recursion, think about the order of the coefficients that you need to input.  Order is important.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yeah, that's just the basic until I get running up with generating coefficients method although as order may not be accurately this little maneuver loop recursion it uses time complexity of O(n-log-n) that should evaluate them multiplying by x^n so to speak that gets done nicely, perhaps you'd be suggesting using Gauss?

Comment: Nice picture for the output scenarios, but what were the numbers, in order, that you gave to your program.  Please edit your post with the text of the information.

Comment: One benefit about using `std::vector` to hold your coefficients, is that you can pass a known set of values to your `horner` function (without having to type them in every time).  Easier to debug.

Comment: Well, maybe trying with a simple loop first instead of doing it recursivley would help.  Computing  polynomial expressions recursively iherently limits the grade of the polynomials you can compute, i.e. bust the stack before the end of the computation. Tip: start looping from degree 0 (the end of the your coef array, since you chose to store with decreasing powers of x).